# Screen scraper application (not HTML)

Tags: c#, ocr, screen-scraping

I need screen scraper application which will recognize text from the screen (and not use winapi to do this so source could be in image file). I found a lot of commercial solutions, but I need something open source or free.
I plan to include it in my C# project, so there should be some SDK available.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Tessnet](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) to do character recognition of your images.  If you want to screen scrape the desktop, you could potentially just take a screen shot, turn it into an image, and use the OCR library above.

Comment: Thank you for link, but I can't achieve stable behavior from Tessnet. Depending on input image it could recognize text, output "~ (100)" (don’t know what app means by that yet) or shutdown without any particular error. I’ve downloaded tesseract sources and build these projects manually, but still don’t have positive results. Now trying to debug it. I’ve also tried to use MODI but it makes a mistakes even in simple text grabbed from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, I have found [screen scraper](http://community.screen-scraper.com/Tutorials_Menu) useful for applying patterns against a web site and saving the data that I care about. The tutorial page should give you an idea of what it does.

Screen Scraper's [free edition](http://screen-scraper.com/download/choose_version.php) allows scripting in Interpreted Java, JScript, JavaScript, Python, and VBScript... is that close enough?